# Опечатка на странице “Отмечать тревогой”

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, тревоги

На странице "Отмечать тревогой", опечатка в заголовке ["Что такое сингал тревоги?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Насколько я правильно понимаю, нужно:

> Что такое сигнал тревоги?

Справка > Привилегии > Отмечать тревогой

> [image: Скриншот]

Comment: Стивен Сингал тревоги :)

Comment: Передал информацию куда нужно, скоро опечатка будет исправлена.

Comment: [ибо](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjJyg.jpg)

Comment: Вопросом не занимаются, потому что у кого есть полномочия, тем не интересно. А кому интересно - не имеют полномочий. Самоуправление без инструментария невозможно.

Comment: Значит подобного рода сообщения не имеют никакого значения и их не нужно оставлять на Мете?

Comment: @Kyper нужно, однако приоритеты руководства не часто совпадают с желаниями пользователей.

Comment: @Kyper Спасибо за отзыв! Опечатку поправил. Пожалуйста, если вы видите, что подобное не исправляется довольно долго, упомяните в чате модераторов или меня (мы все имеем доступ для правки справочного центра).